# Vim neocomplete auto suggestion

Tags: vim

I am using Vim Neocomplete plugin.
How does neocomplete's auto suggest for char's between a string work?

Ex-

```
def machine_share():
pass
```

Now, if I type `share` how can I make neocomplete to auto suggest `machine_share` ?
NOTE: By auto suggest, I mean omnicompletion.

Answer (score 0):

That kind of completion which considers the text *after* the cursor (possibly in addition to the usual completion base before the cursor) is implemented by my [BidiComplete plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4658).

If the Neocomplete plugin allows to integrate custom completions (I don't know that plugin), you can do so. If it only supports `'completefunc'`, you can

```
:set completefunc=BidiComplete#BidiComplete
```

Otherwise, you have to trigger this special kind of completion via the separate `<C-X><C-B>` key combination from insert mode (or remap it).